# How to get the type of a validated field in Pydantic validator method

Tags: python-3.x, validation, pydantic, python-dataclasses

I want to assign a value of None to a field that fails to validate in Pydantic. The validator has a list of fields that it tries to validate.

To validate each field using `data, fields_set, e = validate_model(model, raw_data)` I need to know the model of each field.

I would like to have something like this for a validator.

Is there a way to discover the type of the field that is being validated???

```
    @validator('*', pre=True)
    def validate_name(cls, value: str):
        model_of_field = ..... Some method to discover the field's Type(s)
        data, fields_set, e = validate_model(model_of_field, value)
        return value
```

---

**Example that declares a separate validator method for each field**

Note that the field is named "name1" on purpose to fail the validation and make it return None.

```
from typing import Any, Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator, validate_model, ValidationError


class NameModel(BaseModel):
    name: str


class AgeModel(BaseModel):
    age: int


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    name_data: Optional[NameModel]
    age_data: Optional[AgeModel]

    @classmethod
    def pre_validate_any_field_and_return_none_on_validation_error(cls, model: Any,  value: Any):
        data, fields_set, e = validate_model(model, value)
        if e:
            return None
        else:
            return value


    @validator('name_data', pre=True)
    def validate_name(cls, value: str):
        return cls.pre_validate_any_field_and_return_none_on_validation_error(NameModel, value)


    @validator('age_data', pre=True)
    def validate_age(cls, value: int):
        return cls.pre_validate_any_field_and_return_none_on_validation_error(AgeModel, value)


my_data = {
    'name_data': {'name1': 'Hello_a'},
    'age_data': {'age': 120}
}

my_object: MyModel = MyModel(**my_data)
print(my_object)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `__fields__` property as documented here: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#model-properties. It will give you something like this:

```py
class Model(BaseModel):
    value: int

    @field_validator("value", mode='before')
    def validate_value(cls, v):
        print(cls.__fields__)
        # Do your logic here
        return v

Model(1)
```

This would print:

```json
{'value': ModelField(name='value', type=int, required=True)}
```

Comment: Note that the use of `__fields__` has been deprecated. Use the `cls.model_fields` property instead.